# How do I set up Visual Studio for retrieving data from SharePoint lists?

Tags: development

We use a SharePoint site as a store of data using lists. 
Could you please explain how I can set up Visual Studio to retrieve the data in those lists using .NET Core/C#?

I want to be able to post data to the lists and also retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install Microsoft Office Developer Tools. Refer [this](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/) link for reference
2. Create a SharePoint solution and a Visual WebPart in that solution. Refer [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/programmatically-insert-items-into-sharepoint-list/) link for reference
3. Code for posting a new item in a list is as below:

   ```
   using(SPSite oSite = new SPSite("http://testSite:3100")) {  
   using(SPWeb oWeb = oSite.RootWeb){  
       SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["Details"];  
       SPListItem oSPListItem = oList.Items.Add();   
       oSPListItem["City"] = txtCity.Text;  
       oSPListItem["State"] = txtState.Text;
       oSPListItem.Update();  
       }  
   }
   ```
4. For reading list/library items refer below code:

   ```
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite("Your Site URL"))
           {
               using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
               {

                   if (web != null)
                   {
                       SPList list = web.Lists["Your List Name"];
                       SPListItemCollection items = GetListItems(list);
                       if (items.Count > 0)
                       {
                           //This will give your all the folders in root folder
                           foreach (SPFolder folder in list.RootFolder.SubFolders)
                           {
                               //This is the default folder which is not visible so skip this
                               if (folder.Name.ToLower() != "_w")
                               {
                                   SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                   query.Folder = folder;
                                   SPListItemCollection listitem = list.GetItems(query);
                                   if (listitem.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //This will return you the current folder name
                                       string Name = folder.Name;
                                       //This will return you the total number of items in that folder
                                       int count = folder.ItemCount;
                                       //Thi will return you the Title of the first Item. You Can also use loop here to iterate through all items
                                       string Title = listitem[0]["Title"];
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }

                   }

               }

           }
   ```
5. For performing CRUD operation on list item using JavaScript and CSOM refer below links.
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am interested in developing for sharepoint without installing sharepoint server since that requires substantial resources. Can I do this using the client object model? If so, what are the necessary steps?